# i want images to fadeIn-fadeOut automatically with particular time interval, instead of click

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm posting my codes here and i've made images fadIn-fadeOut on click function, but i want them to fadeIn-fadeOut automatically with particular time interval. So how can i achieve that, please help me out.

http://jsfiddle.net/8jigarpatel/P4ANC/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    fO();
}, 1000);
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P4ANC/5/

Comment: okay..can you specify exactly where to place it?

   var imgsrc = ["images/c1.png", "images/c2.png", "images/c3.png", "images/c4.png", "images/c5.png"];
   var imgnum = 0;
   
   $('#cfifo').click(function(){
   $('#cfifoimg').fadeOut((300),function(){
          imgnum++;
         if(imgnum>4) {imgnum=0;}
         $(this).attr("src",imgsrc[imgnum]);
         $(this).fadeIn(300);
      });
   });
});

Answer (score 0):

Something i did a while ago. Uses 2 image containers (so that you can fade from one image to another):

```
var img2 = true;
var imgChangeDelay = 5;
var currentImg = 2;
var images = [
    'mainImg.jpg',
    'mainImg_6.jpg',
    'mainImg_2.jpg',
    'mainImg_3.jpg',
    'mainImg_7.jpg',
    'mainImg_8.jpg'
];

function switchImages() {
    if(img2) {
        img2 = false;
        $(".rightMainImage").css('background', 'url("/img/mainPhotos/'+images[currentImg]+'") no-repeat');
        $(".rightMainImage2").animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
            setTimeout("switchImages();", (imgChangeDelay*1000));
        });
    } else {
        img2 = true;
        $(".rightMainImage2").css('background', 'url("/img/mainPhotos/'+images[currentImg]+'") no-repeat');
        $(".rightMainImage2").animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
            setTimeout("switchImages();", (imgChangeDelay*1000));
        });
    }
    if(currentImg == (images.length - 1)) {
        currentImg = 0;
    } else {
        currentImg++;
    }
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div class="rightMainImage">
    <div class="rightMainImage2"></div>
</div>
```

Style for image containers:

```
.rightMainImage, .rightMainImage2 {
    width: 569px;
    float: right;
    height: 335px;
    background: url("/img/mainPhotos/mainImg.jpg") no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

And don't forget to add it to page startup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout("switchImages();", (imgChangeDelay*1000));
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanz a lot friend, hope it will help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery you can use animation-chaining and the [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function, to create a delay for a specific amount of time between the fadeOut and fadeIn.

A simple example, which delays for 1 sec, fades-out a div, delays for 1 sec, and then fades it back in again:

**Javascript:**

```
$('#myDiv').delay(1000).fadeOut(300).delay(1000).fadeIn(300);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myDiv" style="background-color: red; width:200px; height:200px;"></div>
```

**Javascript V2:**

Or a little more advanced, if we want to change the background-color of the div to yellow before fading in again. 
(This is similar to your case, where you want to change picture before the image element is being faded in again)

```
$('#myDiv').delay(1000).fadeOut(300, function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","yellow"); // set background to yellow before fading in
}).delay(1000).fadeIn(300);
```

**Javascript V3:**

Finally, a way to also make the animation loop is the following:

```
function start() {
    $('#myDiv').delay(1000)
               .fadeOut(300, function() {$(this).css("background-color","yellow");})
               .delay(1000)
               .fadeIn(300, start);
}
start();
```

I've created a function called start, which is called when the animation stops in order to start it again. (and of course it's also called to start it for the first time)

.
**Your example:**

From the code you posted on jsfiddle, something like this will work: (sorry for the inline javascript)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                var imgsrc = ["images/c1.png", "images/c2.png", "images/c3.png", "images/c4.png", "images/c5.png"];
                var imgnum = 0;

                function start() {
                    $('#cfifoimg').delay(1000).fadeOut(300, function() {
                        imgnum++;
                        if(imgnum>4) {imgnum=0;}
                        $(this).attr("src",imgsrc[imgnum]);
                    }).delay(1000).fadeIn(300, start);
                }
                start();

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cfifo">
            <img id="cfifoimg" src="images/c1.png"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Important:** Not all JQuery functions can be chained like this - see http://api.jquery.com/delay/ for more information